# Troubleshooting Frame Reception and JPEG Saving with GStreamer in C SDK WebRTC

Tags: c, amazon-web-services, webrtc, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I'm working on modifying the WebRTC C SDK for sending and receiving streams on Amazon Kinesis based on [here](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-webrtc-sdk-c/blob/master/samples/kvsWebrtcClientMasterGstSample.c). Specifically, I've implemented custom functionalities within the `sendGstreamerAudioVideo` and `receiveGstreamerAudioVideo` functions in my .c file, assuming that the kvslugin is installed (source [here](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-demos/tree/master/gst/gst-kvs-plugin)).

File `main.c`

```
#include "Samples.h"
#include <gst/gst.h>
#include <gst/app/gstappsink.h>

PVOID receiveGstreamerAudioVideo(PVOID args){
   ...
   pipeline = gst_parse_launch("filesrc location=./samples.mp4 ! x264enc "
               " ! kvsplugin stream-name=Foo channel-name=Foo log-level=3", &error);
   ...
}

PVOID sendGstreamerAudioVideo(PVOID args){
    ...
    gchar* fileSinkDescription = "multifilesink name=multifilesink location=./test_rtc/frame_%d.h264";
    audioVideoDescription = g_strjoin(" ", audioDescription, videoDescription, fileSinkDescription, NULL);
    pipeline = gst_parse_launch(audioVideoDescription, &error);
    appsrcAudio = gst_bin_get_by_name(GST_BIN(pipeline), "appsrc-audio");
    ...
}

INT32 main(INT32 argc, CHAR* argv[])
{
    ...
    STATUS retStatus = STATUS_SUCCESS;
    PSampleConfiguration pSampleConfiguration = NULL;
    pSampleConfiguration->videoSource = sendGstreamerAudioVideo;
    pSampleConfiguration->mediaType = SAMPLE_STREAMING_VIDEO_ONLY;
    pSampleConfiguration->receiveAudioVideoSource = receiveGstreamerAudioVideo;

    ... 
    CHK_STATUS(initKvsWebRtc());

    CHK_STATUS(initSignaling(pSampleConfiguration, SAMPLE_MASTER_CLIENT_ID));

    // Checking for termination
    CHK_STATUS(sessionCleanupWait(pSampleConfiguration));
    ...
}
```

File `Sample.h`:

```
#include <com/amazonaws/kinesis/video/webrtcclient/Include.h>
typedef struct {
    ...
    startRoutine audioSource;
    startRoutine videoSource;
    startRoutine receiveAudioVideoSource;
    SampleStreamingMediaType mediaType;
    ...
} SampleConfiguration, *PSampleConfiguration;
```

While testing, I am unsure about the successful launch of the pipeline. The code runs without errors, but the printf statements within `sendGstreamerAudioVideo` and `receiveGstreamerAudioVideo` functions do not produce any output.

I would expect the video send to Kinesis Stream and frames are extracted and saved locally. Any assistance in troubleshooting would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.